# How do I Bake Backfacing or Two-Sided Textures?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

How would you bake back facing or two sided textures? It seems like it should be a simple solution. I've tried a handful of searches here and elsewhere and I can't find a solution. Please link if it's out there.

Here's my setup:

[image]

Two Textures: Top and Bottom with a Geometry Node / Backfacing. This combo generates, Color, Alpha and Bump / Normal data. There is a lonely new Image Texture at the bottom waiting to be Baked...

How would you bake this texture?

Any help is sincerely appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you just wanting it to be baked to help simplify the node network or something? I honestly feel like there's only so simple you can go with a two-sided material. If you're just looking to simplify it might work better to just combine both texture "sides" into one image in photoshop or something and then use that. But no matter what you're going to need a Backfacing mask, two bumps, two roughnesses, two base colors, or both combined onto a single set of textures, no matter what.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I guess I see that. I'm trying to bake because I'm animating a much larger scene, with a dozen similar textures and I'm trying to get render times down. Maybe baking won't create any advantage there if I'm just rebuilding the same node tree again.

Comment: Yeah usually in that scenario baking would help if the material made heavy use of procedural textures, with a lot of like Voronoi or Musgrave textures, stuff like that. Since those node rely on such complex math to generate their output.